# MySQL Server Refusing Local Connections Over SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, putty

I have a remote Windows server with MySQL and Cygwin (enabling remote SSH connections). When I connect from a local instance of Workbench (i.e. with Workbench handling the tunnel), via SSH as root, I have no problem connecting to the remote database.

I have a need to set up my own tunnel because I have another app that needs MySQL access. I chose to use Putty, and had only partial success.

I can connect (using Workbench as a test client) through my tunnel, localhost:3307, which I have forwarded to myremoteserver.no-ip.com:3306, ONLY if I have the remote root user there set to accept connections from all hosts (%), AND/OR the actual IP of the server.

If I restrict root to 127.0.0.1 (as it should be) I get the error `Host x.x.x.x is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` where x.x.x.x is the actual address of the remote server!

Somehow, using Putty to make the tunnel isn't presenting me as a local connection. But instead as a remote connection, even though the remote IP is the IP of the remote server

My Question: How can I set up putty to mimic the way Workbench successfully makes tunnel connections?

Note: All my connections to the remote IP are via a no-ip address. This works when Workbench opens the tunnel. Also my server is run within the AWS EC2 ecosystem.

My current Putty connection is to the no-ip address and tunneling settings are `Source:3307, Destination: myremoteserver.no-ip.com:3306, Local and Auto`.

**Edit: I have also tried `127.0.0.1:3306` as the destination address in the Putty tunnel settings and got the same result.**

Answer (score 1):

> My current Putty connection is to the no-ip address and tunneling
>   settings are Source:3307, Destination: myremoteserver.no-ip.com:3306,
>   Local and Auto.

You want to restrict the remote instance of mysql to only accept connections on the localhost interface, so your tunnel should forward to the remote host's localhost interface instead of its network interface. Change the tunnel's destination address to `127.0.0.1` instead of the server's name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed I tried that last night and the result is the same for `127.0.0.1:3306` set as the destination address in Putty. I will update the question detailing this observation too.